# ip address updation in openflow

Tags: sdn, openflow, pox

I am trying to modify the destination address for an incoming ping request at the switch using a POX controller. I use packet.next to modify the destination address. Once this address is modified I create a new packet with the incoming source IP and the new destination IP. But my pings aren't getting through. I also make sure that the nw destination of the message is modified before it is sent to the switch.

It will be really helpful if someone can help me solve this issue.

I'm using the l3_learning.py sample program present in Mininet.

I've added this condition in the handle_PacketIn function to the `ifinstance(packet.next,arp)`.

My code

```
 : : if str(packet.src)==str("00:00:00:00:00:19") and (inport)==19: packet.src = EthAddr("00:00:00:00:00:22") inport = 22 if str(packet.dst)==str("00:00:00:00:00:19") and inport==19: a1.protosrc = IPAddr("10.0.0.6") a1.hwsrc = EthAddr("00:00:00:00:00:22")
```

I then send an ARP packet.

I have changed the `nw_dst using ofp.match() –`

Comment: Hi Shubha! Can you add the code that you have implemented thus far?

Comment: Hi Brandon..I'm using the l3_learning.py sample program present in Mininet. I've added this condition in the handle_PacketIn function to the ifinstance(packet.next,arp). My code : : if str(packet.src)==str("00:00:00:00:00:19") and (inport)==19:
                packet.src = EthAddr("00:00:00:00:00:22")
                inport = 22
            if str(packet.dst)==str("00:00:00:00:00:19") and inport==19:
                a1.protosrc = IPAddr("10.0.0.6")
                a1.hwsrc = EthAddr("00:00:00:00:00:22"). I then send an ARP packet. I have chenged the nw_dst using ofp.match()

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Instead of programming flows I was directly trying to modify the packets to redirect to the hosts. That was why I was unable to get a ping response.